# is my understanding of ES modules correct

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

So I thought about ES modules lately and this is how I think they work:

1. There's a global object that can't be accessed by a user (let's call it `#moduleMap`). It maps modules absolute urls to their exports:

```
#moduleMap = {
  "https://something.com/module.mjs": { exportName: "value" }
}
```

2. The procedure for evaluating a module is as follows:

   - module is fetched
   - module is parsed to ast
   - ast is modified as follows:

`import { x } from "./module1.mjs"` => all `x` references are replaced with 
`#moduleMap["abs path module1.mjs"].x` (and imported module is being fetched)

`export const y = "some value"` => `#moduleMap["abs path to this module"].y = "some value"`

(as @Bergi pointed out it's not that simple with exports because exports are not hoisted so dead zone for consts and hoisting for functions are not reflected with just property assignments)

(the above is what's called binding that produce 'live bindings')

- the operation is repeated for each module imported
- when all modules are fetched, parsed and modified the evaluation starts from the entry module (each module is executed in isolation (~wapped in an IIFE with strict mode on).

As @Bergi pointed out, modules are evaluated eagerly starting from the entry module and evaluating module's imports before the module code itself is executed (with exception for circular dependencies) which practically means the import that was required last will be executed first.

- when evaluation reaches any code that accesses `#moduleMap["some module"]`, the browser checks if the module was evaluated

  - if it wasn't evaluated it is evaluated at this point after which the evaluation returns to this place (now the module (or its exports to be exact) is 'cached' in `#moduleMap`)
- if it was evaluated the import is accessible from `#moduleMap["some module"].someImport`

for situations where an import is reassigned from other module the browser throws an error

That's basically all is happening AFAIK. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have a pretty good understanding but there are a few anomalies that should be corrected.

### ES Modules

In ECMA-262, all modules will have this general shape:

```
Abstract Module {
  Environment // Holds lexical environment for variables declared in module
  Namespace   // Exotic object that reaches into Environment to access exported values

  Instantiate()
  Evaluate()
}
```

There are a lot of different places that modules can come from, so there are "subclasses" of this [Abstract Module](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-module-records). The one we are talking about here is called a [Source Text Module](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-source-text-module-records).

```
Source Text Module : Abstract Module {
  ECMAScriptCode     // Concrete syntax tree of actual source text
  RequestedModules   // List of imports parsed from source text
  LocalExportEntries // List of exports parsed from source text

  Evaluate()         // interprets ECMAScriptCode
}
```

When a variable is declared in a module (`const a = 5`) it is stored in the module's [`Environment`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-environment-records). If you add an `export` declaration to that, it will also show up in LocalExportEntries.

When you `import` a module, you are actually grabbing the `Namespace` object, which has *exotic* behaviour, meaning that while it appears to be a normal object, things like getting and setting properties might do different things than what you were expecting.

In the case of [Module Namespace Objects](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-objects), getting a property `namespace.a`, actually looks up that property as a name in the associated `Environment`.

So if I have two modules, A, and B:

```
// A
export const a = 5;
```

```
// B
import { a } from 'A';

console.log(a);
```

Module B imports A, and then in module B, `a` is bound to `A.Namespace.a`. So whenever `a` is accessed in module `b`, it actually looks it up on `A.Namespace`, which looks it up in `A.Environment`. (This is how live bindings actually work).

Finally onto the subject of your module map. All modules will be Instantiated before they can be Evaluated. Instantiation is the process of resolving the module graph and preparing the module for Evaluation.

### Module Map

The idea of a "module map" is implementation specific, but for the purposes of browsers and node, it looks like this: `Module Map <URL, Abstract Module>`.

A good way to show how browsers/node use this module map is dynamic `import()`:

```
async function import(specifier) {
  const referrer = GetActiveScriptOrModule().specifier;
  const url = new URL(specifier, referrer);
  if (moduleMap.has(url)) {
    return moduleMap.get(url).Namespace;
  }
  const module = await FetchModuleSomehow(url);
  moduleMap.set(url, module);
  return module.Namespace;
}
```

You can actually see this exact behaviour in Node.js: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e24fc95398e89759b132d07352b55941e7fb8474/lib/internal/modules/esm/loader.js#L98

Comment: Pretty low-level explanations - a bit too low-level for me at this point but quite interesting nevertheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> `export const y = "some value"` => `#moduleMap["abs path to this module"].y = "some value"`
>
> (the above is what's called binding that produce 'live bindings')

Yeah, basically - you correctly understood that they all reference the same thing, and when the module reassigns it the importers will notice that.

However, it's a bit more complicated as `const y` stays a `const` variable declaration, so it still is subject to the temporal dead zone, and `function` declarations are still subject to hoisting. This isn't reflected well when you think of exports as properties of an object.

> - when evaluation reaches any code that accesses `#moduleMap["some module"]`, the browser checks if the module was evaluated
>
>   - if it wasn't evaluated it is evaluated at this point after which the evaluation returns to this place (now the module (or its exports to be exact) is 'cached' in `#moduleMap`)
>   - if it was evaluated the import is accessible from `#moduleMap["some module"].someImport`

No. Module evaluation doesn't happen lazily, when the interpreter comes across the first reference to an imported value. Instead, modules are evaluated strictly in the order of the `import` statements (starting from the entry module). A module does not start to be evaluated before all of its dependencies have been evaluated (apart from when it has a circular dependency on itself).

Comment: Really good points. Thanks for catching them, I really appreciate it. As to first point, modules can only be imported at module's top level and are basically evaluated first even if they are at the bottom of the file so while variable/function declarations aren't equal to property assignments (because of dead zone/hoisting), (when it comes to just imports) this doesn't matter because the behavior is the same (consts/functions are available from any place in the module because imports are 'hoisted'). But exports are completely different story and there it matters (exports are not hoisted!). Thx

Comment: i think the module will be evaluated before any circular dependency it imports (not only on itself). Right?

Comment: @marzelin Yeah, hoisting/TDZ only matters within the module itself, and when there are circular dependencies.

Comment: @marzelin In a circular dependency, it still tries to evaluate in import order, but when it hits a module that already is getting initialised (i.e. when it has closed a circle), that module is ignored and imported without being evaluated. E.g. if A depends on B and B depends on A, when you import A then first A's variables and functions are declared and imported into B, then B's variables and functions are declared, then B is evaluated (without A having been evaluated), then A is evaluated (with the B exports), and then your top module (that imported A) is getting evaluated.

Comment: hmm..., in your example, when in B I try to access an import from A (at top level in B) I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: exportName is not defined`. It would suggest that exports from circular dependecy are still not declared when the module is evaluated.

Comment: @marzelin Does "defined" mean "declared" or "initialised"? Also, what environment are you running this in? Anything with a module transpiler/bundler will hardly be able to correctly represent this. Regardless, circular dependencies are an edge case and should not be required to understand how import/export works :-)

Comment: I run it in Chrome 68 which has a native module support. Anyways, thanks I've learnt a lot :)

Comment: hi @Bergi, thanks for the explanation of how circular dependencies resolution works under the hood. The result can be seen in https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rvbju7?file=index.mjs, works like a charm. However, if I change file extensions of files containing modules `a` and `b` to `.js`, I get a circular dependency error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sjrdft?file=index.mjs :( the `type` in package.json is set to `module`, so in my understanding `.js` and `.mjs` should behave the same; reality is different. Do you, just in case, know why?

Comment: @grreeenn I cannot reproduce